# I want to click on a <li> and get the id to insert it into database via POST, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<form method="POST">
Something: <input type="text" name="input" />
    <ul>
          <li id="data1">Data 1</li>
          <li id="data1">Data 2</li>
          <li id="data1">Data 3</li>
        </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
```

I would like to insert that data throught php if it was possible.
This is the code in php

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`
`$db=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "databasename");`
`$text=$_POST['input'];`
`$data=???????;`
`$insert=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tablename (text, data) VALUES ('".$text."', '".$data."'); }`

-------UPDATE------

```
<li id="data1">Data 1</li>
<li id="data2">Data 2</li>
<li id="data3">Data 3</li>
```

Comment: _So what is the question_ ?

Comment: I want to click on that div and get the id to insert it into database

Comment: `div` ? There isn't any in the provided markup..

Comment: Ups, sorry, the <li>

Comment: __ID MUST BE UNIQUE__

Comment: Done, updated, each have a unique id

Comment: On which event, you want to do DB operation ?

Comment: onclick if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
     data = this.id;
     text = $('input:textbox').val();
     $.ajax({
         type="post",
         url = "save.php",
         data = {"text":text, "data":data},
         success = function() {
          }
      });
});
```

save.php will be like this

```
 $db=mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "databasename");
    $text=$_POST['text']; 
    $data=$_POST['data']; 
    $insert=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tablename  (text,data)                          
    VALUES        
    ('".$text."', '".$data."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "ul" better use "select" since this element implements the idea of posting a selected value.

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
    Something: <input type="text" name="input" />
    <select name="data">
        <option value="data1">Data 1</option>
        <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
        <option value="data3">Data 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Greetz

Edit:
Another way is to use ajax sending a custom request to the server.
Take this as an example:

```
<div class="myForm">
    Something: <input type="text" name="input" id="input" />
    <ul class="myList">
        <li data-id="data1">Data 1</li>
        <li data-id="data2">Data 2</li>
        <li data-id="data3">Data 3</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="send" />
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.myList li").click(function(){
            //remove all selected classes
            $.each("ul.myList li", function(){
                $(this).removeClass("active");
            });
            //Set current as active
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

        $("#send").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "PathToFile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {text: $("#input").val(), data: $("ul.myList li.active").attr("data-id"),
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know I could use select, but I want to try other ways to make it look pretty, but if I can't find an answer, I will do it in a select.

Comment: It is possible using an ajax-request.
There you can add additional post data into the request, including your li selection.

Comment: But I can add the `<input type="text">` via AJAX too?

Comment: I will write another example gimme a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to find all the `li` elements. Use a `loop` to bind `click` events to those elements.

Keep `hidden` input element in the `DOM` and update its value when value is changed.

```js
var liElems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
[].forEach.call(liElems, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector("[name='data']").value = this.id;
    document.dataForm.submit();
  });
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" name='dataForm'>
  Something:
  <input type="text" name="input" />
  <ul>
    <li id="data1">Data 1</li>
    <li id="data2">Data 2</li>
    <li id="data3">Data 3</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name='data'>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0wp2hLd7/)

Comment: Just a question, what does the  `document.dataForm.submit();`?

Comment: It will submit the form..As I guessed that you want to submit the form with `id` value as a post argument on click..